# Do ginko trees grow well in Eastern North America (specifically Ontario,Canada)

Tags: botany, trees

I have recently noticed many Ginko (*Ginko biloba*) saplings planted in my Eastern Ontario city (in Canada), and they are looking a bit sickly, with yellow leaves.
They seem to be a popular choice in new developments, but I didn't think they grew well in the region (which is in Hardiness Zone 5).  Could the yellowing leaves just be poor management, or are the poorly suited to the region?

Wikipedia tells me that although these trees are native to China, they have been cultivated in North America for 200 years.

Comment: It took a little bit of digging (no pun intended), but this seemed to be a resource provided by Tree Ontario/Forest Ontario. http://www.seedlingnursery.com/resources/item/21-choosing-the-right-tree . Your best bet is always to ask a nursery or [parks service](http://www.ontarioparks.com/en) in your local area. They usually have professionals with a great deal of knowledge on local conditions and the best choices based on weather, growing season, soil conditions, drainage, and indigenous parasites.

Comment: I have now spotted several ginko trees that appear to be mature and healthy; and established in residential/park area rather than in an arboretum or educational/research facility.  I conclude that they must be able to survive here.

Comment: As a side note, ginkos are excellent at removing air pollutants and living in toxic environments. It has a wide range of temperature tolerance and is very hardy. It sounds like yours have a possible [magnesium deficiency](http://anrcatalog.ucdavis.edu/pdf/8045.pdf) which is common in gingkos, or the plant might be over or under watered. [A very helpful link all about the gingko, its habitats, and usefulness](http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/2011/lehrer_brit/habitat.htm)

Comment: @AMR I actually disagree (to...some degree). Though there are usually no other options than to speak to a nursery or parks service, these sources are *often* not accurate. Even experienced nursery employees are not always going to get it right. I have experienced this multiple times at nurseries in various US states. Further, while I worked as an environmental educator within the park system, I saw misinformation be presented on numerous occasions. I don't mean to discredit your comment at all, but rather just point out that those sources come with their own risk of inaccuracy.